# Trying to install django-defectDojo helm chart and running into StatefulSet version error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I am trying to follow the installation of helm chart for django-defectDojo on my CentOS machine given here https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/blob/master/KUBERNETES.md

But on running the helm install command I am running into this issue -

> Error: validation failed: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind
>   "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1", unable to recognize "":
>   no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta2"]

On further inspection, I believe this has to do with the postgresql chart but I am unable to resolve the issue.

My kubectl version is

> kubectl version
>
> GitVersion:"v1.17.1",
>   GitCommit:"d224476cd0730baca2b6e357d144171ed74192d6",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-14T21:04:32Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.1",
>   GitCommit:"d224476cd0730baca2b6e357d144171ed74192d6",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-14T20:56:50Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17",

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a problem with this chart and it won't work with newer versions of **Kubernetes** (1.16 and higher) without additional modification. I found [this](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/issues/1631) issue on **django-DefectDojo** github page. [Here](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/issues/1631#issuecomment-549029627) same problem as yours is reported.

The problem is related with some major changes in **Kubernetes APIs** in `version 1.16`.

In [Changelog since v1.15.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#changelog-since-v1150) you can read the following:

> The following APIs are no longer served by default: (#70672, @liggitt)
>   * **All resources under `apps/v1beta1` and `apps/v1beta2` - use `apps/v1` instead** * `daemonsets`, `deployments`, `replicasets` resources under
>   `extensions/v1beta1` - use `apps/v1` instead * `networkpolicies` resources
>   under `extensions/v1beta1` - use `networking.k8s.io/v1` instead *
>   `podsecuritypolicies` resources under `extensions/v1beta1` - use
>   `policy/v1beta1` instead

And further there is even temporary solution provided:

> - Serving these resources can be temporarily re-enabled using the
>     `--runtime-config` apiserver flag.
> - `apps/v1beta1=true`
> - `apps/v1beta2=true`
> - `extensions/v1beta1/daemonsets=true,extensions/v1beta1/deployments=true,extensions/v1beta1/replicasets=true,extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true,extensions/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicies=true`
> - **The ability to serve these resources will be completely removed in v1.18.**

As your Kubernetes version is **1.17**, you can still use this workaround.

Alternatively you can use older **Kubernetes** version as suggested [here](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/issues/1631#issuecomment-549966194) or modify appropriate `yaml` manifests from [django-DefectDojo](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo) project manually by yourself so they match current **Kubernetes** **APIs** structure.

Comment: Setting the runtime flag worked for me. Thank you for helping me out.